# SciFi Movie involving flying spaceships that can split up

Tags: story-identification, movie

At the time, I was living in Germany, so the movie was in German. However, Germany was not known back then to make that type of movie, so I assume it came from somewhere else and was dubbed.

- It was not an animated movie.
- It probably was in the late 80s that I watched it.
- I recall three main characters. Two of them were male and either brothers or good friends. They were flying the spaceship. The female character was coming on board later. There was a battle and the two male characters were at the end flying in two spaceships. Their ship had a way of splitting into two (it was not a shuttle or something). It was that the mainship was able to separate into two (or more) ships.
- If I am not totally mistaken, than one of them dies at the end. But I am not 100% sure of that.

Comment: This is a good description, welcome to SFF! Can you remember any of the plot of this? If you remember anything else please [edit] your question to include those details. You may also wish to take the [tour] to learn more about the site!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sci-fi Movie - the spaceship was unique and broke apart in three separate ships](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158149/sci-fi-movie-the-spaceship-was-unique-and-broke-apart-in-three-separate-ships)

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis both questions need the same confirmed answer in story id to be duplicates. This doesn’t have any answers never mind a confirmed one and neither does the dupe target.

Comment: Also, none of the answers submitted in the other question seem likely to be the correct answer for this one, since they're mostly animations, and the OP here said this was _not_ animated. The only non-animated answer submitted in the other question was _Silent Running_, and that doesn't seem like a good match for this description. So while that other question sounds like it's asking about the same film, it doesn't help us to identify which one is being asked about here.

Comment: @LogicDictates Negative. "San Ku Kai" is non-animated, although I have never heard that it might have been dubbed into German.

Comment: _San Ku Kai_ doesn't seem like a good match either, since it's a TV series, not a movie, and nothing is mentioned about any ship separating. Also, it would be surprising if two separate OPs were asking about a show with an all-Asian cast, and neglected to specify that detail.

Comment: @LogicDictates The San Kyu Kai _is_ the ship that separates into three ("The ensemble of three"), but yeah, there is no indication that this movie was japanese.

Comment: @Windlicht   Germany is not one of the major centers of science fiction film production, but it has produced some science fiction, including 2 claassic films in the 1920s, Metropolis and Womanin the Moon.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:German_science_fiction_films  And some science fiction tv too.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:German_science_fiction_television_series

Comment: @Windlicht  It is a wild guess, but manybe you are remembering the 1958 black and white Roger Corman movie War of the Satellites backwards.  Three parts are launched into space and join together to form a spaceship.  The crew includes at least three men (atleast 2 die) and at least one woman.

Comment: when you say spaceship, do you mean flying through space or something more like the fantastic 4 flying car/ship?

Comment: Was this live-action or something more StarFleety?